# Fetching a single value from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This method is in databasehelperclass returning single value expected

```
  public Cursor getUserDataFromDb(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rawdata=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)",null);
    return rawdata;

}
```

fetching value from usertable inside an Activity

```
    try {
        Cursor cursor = mydb.getUserDataFromDb();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
           name_resultfromdb = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Setup your Account",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using the above code to get the data, but I am getting null.
I want to show this value into a TextView, but I am unable to get it.

Comment: just to know, doing a select all retrieve some data or the table is empty?

Comment: ....or there is no column called NAME (case sensitive)....Think about, if you have tested some stuff with earlier versions of your app and you changed something in database structure, it doesn´t work anymore until you have deleted and rebuild the database.

Comment: i have retrieved the data i wanted using tool if its working or not... its working great...but when i am accessing in activity using cursor its returnig null

Comment: getting `null` where? try checking `cursor.getCount()` value

Comment: yes i have tried that

Comment: i am getting column name but i am not getting string value plz help

Comment: so what's the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) to read a single value:

```java
String result = DatebaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
            "SELECT NAME FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1", null);
```

Anyway, if this query does not return a value, then the table is empty, or the value in the `Name` column of the last record is empty.

Comment: you missed the `stringFromQuery`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thanks!

Comment: i cant find stringFromQuery...stringForQuery is available

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (extra ")"):

```
"SELECT NAME FROM " +TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)"
```

change it to

```
"SELECT NAME FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: thanks ..i just removed that bracket but still not working...table contains data...and i have used sqlite firefox extension to fetch it...its working fine on that...but when running the app still not getting any value

Comment: @user3297303 The Firefox extension is not able to access the database file on the device, so this does not prove anything.

Comment: bro you didnt understant what i said...i meant to say that i used sqlite tool which is firefox extention for sqlite to fetch value from databse